# Шифр Цезаря C++, пробел заменяется символом , не знаю, как исправить

Tags: c++

Что имею сейчас:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string buff;
getline(cin, buff);
for (int i = 0; i < buff.size(); i++)
{

    buff[i] -= 3;
    if (buff[i] == ' ')
    {
        buff[i] += 3;
    }
}
cout << buff << endl;
}
```

Comment: а где тут шифр цезаря?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите, чтобы пробел ничем не заменялся

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string buff;
getline(cin, buff);
for (int i = 0; i < buff.size(); i++)
{
    if (buff[i] != ' ')
    {
        buff[i] -= 3;
    }
}
cout << buff << endl;
}
```